# How can I style the Ace Editor Autocompletion Popup?

Tags: css, ace-editor

When I embed the Ace Editor in a web page and enable autocompletion, I want to be able to style the autocompletion popup.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the css class `.ace_editor.ace_autocomplete`.

For example:

```
.ace_editor.ace_autocomplete {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2)!important;
    width: 50% !important;
}
```